# Setup repository and snapshot in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, swisscomdev

In order to set ES(6.1.4) to backup indices in a S3, I need to configure elasticsearch.yml to set **path.repo**. I can't find anyway to do that.

Can this configuration be accessed from outside?

Thanks

Comment: That is not clear what exactly is your problem? You can  not find file `elasticsearch.yml` or what?

Comment: Exactly. I can't find elasticsearch.yml. This is how I connect to ES:
cf ssh my-indigita-logstash -L 9201:84c.elasticsearch.lyra-2.appcloud.swisscom.com:443 -i 0

Comment: I do use host extracted from elasticsearch env. However this is this seems to be a Logstash server because of the structure of the app folder:
bin  conf.d  curator.conf.d  curator.d  grokpatterns  grok-patterns  Logstash  logstash.conf.d  ofelia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're using an Elasticsearch within the Swisscom Cloud. As this means you have a managed service, you're not able to configure it yourself.
Currently custom S3 backups are not supported by Swisscoms Elasticsearch offering.